# sonar-dotnet-shared-library does not compile due non-existing dependencies, How to make it work?

Tags: c#, maven, plugins, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to compile in my machine the sonar-csharp-plugin, but in the pom.xml file there is two dependencies that do not exist in the [Maven public repositories](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.dotnet):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.sonarsource.dotnet</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-dotnet-tests-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0.393</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.sonarsource.dotnet</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-dotnet-shared-library</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.138</version>
</dependency>
```

I download the code of both projects and try to compile them and generate the .jar files for each one.

Trying to compile sonar-dotnet-shared-library-1.0.1.138, I installed the https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonarAnalyzer.CSharp/1.20.0 package and proceed to install it in my maven local repository then when I compile sonar-dotnet-shared-library-1.0.1.138 I get :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (unzip-nuget) on project sonar-dotnet-shared-library: An Ant Build Exception has occured: C:\Temp\sonar-dotnet-shared-library-1.0.1.138\target\analyzer\SonarAnalyzer.Scanner\protobuf does not exist.
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<copy todir="src/main/protobuf">... @ 8:35 in C:\Temp\sonar-dotnet-shared-library-1.0.1.138\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

I think I am in Maven hell.

What should I do to build the code from the latest release sonar-csharp-plugin??

**Edit:** when I installed the SonarAnalyzer I used

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.sonarsource.dotnet -DartifactId=SonarAnalyzer.Scanner -Dversion=1.20.0 -Dpackaging=nupkg -Dfile="C:\Temp\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.1.20.0-RC1.nupkg"
```

I disable the tasks that generate the error, now the java code start its compilation but I get errors related to

```
import org.sonarsource.dotnet.protobuf.SonarAnalyzer;
```

I think that it is a reference to the SonarAnalyzer Dll's, but neither Eclipse nor Maven are able to find it (protobuf is missing)

**Edit2:**

the POM.XML includes these tasks:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unzip-nuget</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
              <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
              <tasks>
                <unzip src="${sonarAnalyzer.workDirectory}/SonarAnalyzer.Scanner.nupkg" dest="${sonarAnalyzer.workDirectory}/SonarAnalyzer.Scanner/" />
                <delete>
                  <fileset dir="src/main/protobuf" excludes=".gitignore"></fileset>
                </delete>
                <copy todir="src/main/protobuf">
                  <fileset dir="${sonarAnalyzer.workDirectory}/SonarAnalyzer.Scanner/protobuf">
                    <include name="*.proto"/>
                  </fileset>
                </copy>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>compile-protobuf-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <fileset id="fileset" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/protobuf">
                  <include name="*.proto" />
                </fileset>
                <pathconvert refid="fileset" property="protos" pathsep=" " />
                <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/protobuf" />
                <chmod file="${protobuf.compiler}" perm="u+x" />

                <exec failonerror="true" executable="${protobuf.compiler}">
                  <arg value="proto_path=${project.basedir}/src/main/protobuf" />
                  <arg value="java_out=${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/protobuf" />
                  <arg line="${protos}" />
                </exec>  

              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
```

As I understand, in the SonarAnalyzer.Scanner.nupkg should be a protobuf folder, and the content of that folder is copied to src/main/protobuf.....well the SonarAnalyzer.Scanner.nupkg downloaded from Nuget does not contain that folder....so....

guys from Sonar...... Where do I get that nupkg?

Comment: Anyone knows where is org.sonarsource.dotnet.protobuf.SonarAnalyzer???

Comment: I downloaded the nuppkg file from github, and it does not contains the files expected.  :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I've found the solution on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/XOsJ6QrfL60) from SonarQube's Google group.

You need to fetch the missing artifacts from sonarsource's Artifactory server. 
As suggested by Duarte Meneses, you can add these lines to [user_home]/.m2/settings.xml :

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>sonarsource-repo</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>!skip-sonarsource-repo</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>sonarsource</id>
        <name>SonarSource Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repox.sonarsource.com/sonarsource</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <updatePolicy>interval:60</updatePolicy>
          <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
          <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonarsource</id>
        <name>SonarSource Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repox.sonarsource.com/sonarsource</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <!-- no need to always check if new versions are available when
          executing a maven plugin without specifying the version -->
          <updatePolicy>interval:60</updatePolicy>
          <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
          <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

I used the above configuration.
I also had mirrors declared in my settings.xml, so I had to exclude sonarsource from the mirrored repositories :

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*,!sonarsource</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://ci-server/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </mirror>     
</mirrors>
```

Of course there are other ways to achieve the same result, for example by declaring a proxy repository in your company's Nexus server.

With this configuration, I built SonarQube successfully.